# Hack way of opening a cross domain URL using "window.show"Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Using `showModalDialog` or `window.open` in JS to open a URL from the **same** domain in a new window is OK in almost any browsers.

But opening a **cross** domain URL using those functions will be prevented by some browsers like Chrome for security issues.

I am wondering if there is any hack way in Javascript to achieve the open cross domain URL using functions like `showModalDialog` or `window.open`.

Comment: Which URLs does Chrome stop you opening in a `window.open()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but you could try opening a popup that points to your own domain and:

1. Perform a browser redirect to the URL you like
2. Or, create an iframe which occupies the full width and height of the popup page and load the target URL inside it?

Hackish, but works.

Comment: Inspiring. Thanks, worth a try!